# What is best way to multiple dataframe?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have 4 data frame. 
**DF1**
name,id, age

**DF2**
name,id,group

**DF3**
name,id,city

**DF4**
name,id, ctry

I what to join all 4 dataframe with macth of same 'name' and 'id'.
e.g **DF**

**name, id,age,group,city,ctry**

Comment: you can try `val resultDf = DF1.join(DF2,Seq("name","id"))` the same way you can join all the four data frames.

Comment: thanks for the reply, It can be done. But I have to write multiple join lines. Is there any other way to do it in one line or less lines?

Comment: you should be able to add all the dataframes in single line, because join returns another dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
List(df1, df2, df3, df4).reduce(_ join (_, Seq("name", "id")))
```